# Good zoom for imageview inside a viewpager

Tags: android, zooming, android-imageview

I've added the TouchImageView(the one modified by patrick) [this class](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)
inside of my project to make my image zoomable and it works fine but sometimes when you scroll the image till the edges the next image gets placed over it and by that deletes the edges of this image...
plus my image is not filling the page anymore (full screen)..
So how can I fix this?

any help please!!

Answer (score 0):

I found these:

https://gist.github.com/atermenji/3781644
https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

these are just perfect!!!!!!!!